# VB: call a method without initiating class

Tags: vb.net, class

ok so i have a bunch of methods in a class. How can i call those methods with out initiating it like:

```
Dim aa as new classname
aa.method
```

The reason i want to do so is so that i dont have to keep re initiating it to loose its variable data.

In php you can create a static method and then call that method without creating an instance of that class

how can we do this in vb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The static equivalent in VB is Shared